# Unable to pass 2D character array to function(C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, visual-studio-code, computer-science

I am trying to pass a 2-D character array to a function however vs code gives me the following error message:

> cannot convert 'char (*)[3]' to 'char (*)[10]'gcc

Here is the code:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void NodeDetect(char grid[][3], int height, int width)
{
    cout << "\nThe grid output:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            if(grid[i][j] == '0')
            {
                cout << '\n' <<  i << '\t' << j << ", ";

                if(grid[i][j + 1] == '0' && (j + 1) < width)//right neighbour
                    cout << i << '\t' << (j + 1) << ", ";
                else if(grid[i][j + 1] == '.' || (j + 1) == width)
                    cout << "-1 -1, ";

                if(grid[i + 1][j] == '0' && (i + 1) < height)//bottom neighbour
                    cout << (i + 1) << '\t' << j << ", ";
                else if(grid[i + 1][j] == '.' || (i + 1) == height)
                    cout << "-1 -1";
            }
            cout << '\n';
    }
}
int main()
{
    string line;
    char grid[3][3];
    int height, width;                          //height = rows
    cout << "Enter the height and the width:\t";//width = columns
    cin >> height >> width;
    cout << "\nEnter the strings:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)//initializing the grid
        cin >> grid[i];

    /*
    cout << "\nThe grid:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)     //displaying the grid
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            cout << grid[i][j] << '\t';
        cout << '\n';
    }
    */
    NodeDetect(grid, height, width);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to pass the 2D array **grid** to the function **NodeDetect**

Comment: where did the 10 come from?

Comment: After adding `#include <iostream>` I cannot reproduce your compiler error: https://ideone.com/5TSDAI

Comment: @kushagra kartik In the presented code there is no character array with 10 elements. Provide a relevant code.

Comment: Why do you have variables: `height` and `width` that you describe in a comment as `rows` and `columns`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a plain old C-array to a function in C++, you have 2 possibilities.

```
Pass by reference
Pass by pointer
```

It seems that you want to pass by reference. But you are using the wrong syntax.

Please see:

```
void function1(int(&m)[3][4])   // For passing array by reference
{}
void function2(int(*m)[3][4])   // For passing array by pointer
{}

int main()
{
    int matrix[3][4]; // Define 2 dimensional array

    function1(matrix);  // Call by reference
    function2(&matrix); // Call via pointer 
    return 0;
}
```

What you pass to the function is a decayed pointer to array of char.

Simply correct the syntax and it will work.

Additional hint:

Do not use plain C-style arrays in C++. Never. Please use STL containers.